# Can't write any file into bucket only read after gcfuse

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-storage, gcsfuse

I deployed an instance of Wowza Streaming Engine on Google Cloud thank Made a bucket in Google Cloud Storage and mounted it all with GCFUSE. My bucket connected with success and I can see in it and list but I can't write any file with gsutil nor with any FTP even with RSA Key. I also tried gcsfuse -o allow_other but nothing change. What am I doing wrong please help

Answer (score 1):

By default GCE VM instance has `Cloud API access scopes` scope `Storage` set to `Read Only`. It's not enough to set it to `Read Write`. To solve this issue you should set it to `Full` by editing VM instance or using a [gcloud command](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/compute/instances/set-scopes) when the instance turned off.

Please have a look at my steps below:

0. create a new VM instance and bucket (optional):

```
$ gcloud compute instances create instance-1 --zone=us-central1-a --machine-type=e2-medium --image=ubuntu-1804-bionic-v20201014 --image-project=ubuntu-os-cloud
$ gsutil mb gs://test-prj-fuse-bucket-1
```

2. ssh into the VM instance:

```
$ gcloud compute ssh instance-1 --zone=us-central1-a
```

3. install `gsfuse` by following [this article](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcsfuse/blob/master/docs/installing.md):

```
instance-1:~$ export GCSFUSE_REPO=gcsfuse-`lsb_release -c -s`
instance-1:~$ echo "deb http://packages.cloud.google.com/apt $GCSFUSE_REPO main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/gcsfuse.list
instance-1:~$ curl https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg | sudo apt-key add -
instance-1:~$ sudo apt-get update
instance-1:~$ sudo apt-get install gcsfuse
```

4. mount bucket to the VM instance by following [this article](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcsfuse/blob/master/docs/mounting.md):

```
instance-1:~$ mkdir ~/bucket
instance-1:~$ gcsfuse test-prj-fuse-bucket-1 ~/bucket
Using mount point: /home/username/bucket
Opening GCS connection...
Mounting file system...
File system has been successfully mounted.
instance-1:~$ mount | grep gcsfuse
gcsfuse on /home/username/bucket type fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=1001,group_id=1002,default_permissions)
```

5. check access to the bucket:

```
instance-1:~$ cd ~/bucket
instance-1:~/bucket$ touch test
touch: cannot touch 'test': Input/output error
```

so, we're not able to write with default `Cloud API access scopes`.

6. shutdown the VM instance and changes `Cloud API access scopes` with command:

```
$ gcloud beta compute instances set-scopes instance-1 --scopes=storage-full --zone=us-central1-a
```

or via Console.
7. start the VM instance, mount the bucket and check again:

```
$ gcloud compute ssh instance-1 --zone=us-central1-a
instance-1:~$ gcsfuse test-prj-fuse-bucket-1 ~/bucket
instance-1:~/bucket$ touch test
instance-1:~/bucket$ ls 
test
```

everything works now.

Alternatively, you can solve this issue by using service account as it is described below :

By default, GCE instances run as "Compute Engine default service account" which only has read access to GCS objects.

To write to GCS from a GCE instance, do one of the following:

- Create a service account that has the roles/storage.objectAdmin role
- Add the roles/storage.objectAdmin role to your GCE default service
  account

To add the role to your GCE service account using the gcloud utility, run

```
gcloud iam service-accounts list
```

Then find the entry marked "Compute Engine default service account." It will have an email address like `1234567890123-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com.`

To add the role to the GCE service account, run these commands:

```
PROJECT_ID='' # Enter your GCP project ID SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL='' # Enter the service account email you found above 

gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding "$PROJECT_ID" \ --member "serviceAccount:${SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL}" \ --role roles/storage.objectAdmin
```

Have a look at this [Google Group thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gce-discussion/594J75Vj1oM), in order to successfully mount the bucket as a file system using Cloud Storage Fuse. For more details about the subject check this [document](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gcs-fuse#using).

Answer (score 0):

Summarizing our discussion at this [Google Group thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gce-discussion/594J75Vj1oM), in order to successfully mount the bucket as a file system using Cloud Storage Fuse, and in addition to the proper Linux permissions, you need to set proper Google Cloud Storage permissions or role (through IAM) for the service account in use by the VM instance.

Therefore, and since the Compute Engine default service account has an editor role on the project, it is simplest to use it given that you assign the Cloud Storage Scope to the instance itself. For more details about the subject check this [document](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gcs-fuse#using).

Answer (score 0):

By default, GCE instances run as "Compute Engine default service account" which only has read access to GCS objects.

To write to GCS from a GCE instance, do one of the following:

- Create a service account that has the `roles/storage.objectAdmin` role
- Add the `roles/storage.objectAdmin` role to your GCE default service account

To add the role to your GCE service account using the [`gcloud` utility](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/install), run

```
gcloud iam service-accounts list
```

Then find the entry marked "Compute Engine default service account." It will have an email address like `1234567890123-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com`.

To add the role to the GCE service account, run these commands:

```
PROJECT_ID='' # Enter your GCP project ID
SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL='' # Enter the service account email you found above

gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding "$PROJECT_ID" \
  --member "serviceAccount:${SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL}" \
  --role roles/storage.objectAdmin
```